# Cast varbinary to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL below:

```
select substring(hash1,1,4) from (
    select hashbytes('SHA1', 'Ian' + 'Maria') as hash1
    ) as hashtable
```

which returns:

```
0xC0326BA0
```

There are eight characters returned: i.e. 0X + 8 characters.  Why is there 8 characters returned? I realise this is a simple question, but I have not managed to find an answer tonight.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `SUBSTRING` on a binary data type, it returns `length` bytes, not characters, so in this case, you're getting back the four bytes `C0`, `32`, `6B`, and `A0`.

If you really need exactly 4 characters of random binary data interpreted as a string, you could do this:

```
select substring(CAST(hash1 as varchar(4)),1,4) from (
    select hashbytes('SHA1', 'Ian' + 'Maria') as hash1
    ) as hashtable
```

But it won't necessarily be data that means anything.

Comment: never cast as varchar without specifying the size of the varchar.  In a select it will default to 30 characters but I know I have run into other places where it defaults to 1. In any event, you should not be sloppy about this. What if you were casting something larger than 30 characters. So every time you do it , you are building a bad habit that will come back to bite you eventually.

Comment: @HLGEM I fixed the cast.